# React query - useQuery() No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-query

I am getting this two errors that I am unable to explain nor solve, can anyone help me debug this problems.

1. startDateIndex is missing in type, while I have declared the type in `UseWeatherOptions`
2. `useQuery()` No overload matches this call. Should I remove the config

```js
export const getWeatherForecast = ({
  startDateIndex,
}: {
  startDateIndex: number;
}): Promise<IWeatherForecast[]> => {
  return axios.get(`api/WeatherForecasts?startDateIndex=${startDateIndex}`);
};

type UseWeatherOptions = {
  startDateIndex: number;
  config?: QueryConfig<typeof getWeatherForecast>;
};

// Property 'startDateIndex' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'UseWeatherOptions'.ts(2741)
export const useWeather = ({ startDateIndex, config }: UseWeatherOptions = {}) => {
  // No overload matches this call.
  return useQuery({
    ...config,
    queryKey: ['weather', startDateIndex],
    queryFn: () => getWeatherForecast({ startDateIndex }),
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ad 1:  startDateIndex is missing in type, while I have declared the type in UseWeatherOptions

your `type UseWeatherOptions` defines `startDateIndex` as a `number`, so it's a required field. That means you can't initialize `UseWeatherOptions` to an empty object, because an empty object does not contain `startDateIndex`.

To fix this, you can make `startDateIndex` optional by defining it as:

```
startDateIndex?: number
```

or provide a default value:

```
export const useWeather = ({ startDateIndex, config }: UseWeatherOptions = { startDateIndex: 0 }) => {
```

in which case `startDateIndex` will be `0` when you call `useWeather()` without parameters (if that's what you want).

---

ad 2: useQuery() No overload matches this call. Should I remove the config

You are using the wrong type. The `options` passed to `useQuery` are not of type `QueryConfig`, but of type `UseQueryOptions`.

However, that interface has 4 generics, so if you want to provide an abstraction over `useQuery` that allows allows passing in all the `options`, you would need to make your function generic as well.

I would usually not make such an abstraction, because it means every call to `useWeather` could potentially pass in all possible query options, some of which will not make sense if they are different for multiple calls (like `cacheTime`). Also, the minimal thing you would need to do is to `Omit` the `queryFn` and the `queryKey`, because you have that hardcoded. So something along these lines:

```
function useWeather<
  TQueryFnData,
  TError,
  TData = TQueryFnData,
  TQueryKey = QueryKey,
>(
  startDateIndex: number,
  options?: Omit<
    UseQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>,
    "queryKey" | "queryFn"
  >
) {
  return useQuery({
    ...options
    queryKey: ['weather', startDateIndex],
    queryFn: () => getWeatherForecast({ startDateIndex }),
  });
}
```

In most of the cases, it is a lot better to provide abstractions that only allow to pass in the options that you would really like consumers of your custom hook to pass in. Like, should the query run in an interval sometimes? Let them pass in `refetchInterval: number`, etc ...